# Upstream/downstream callers

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, terminology

In VS2010's code analysis, there is a concept of upstream/downstream callers. What exactly is an up/downstream caller?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't it downstream callees ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you have a solution with a couple of projects - `Website`, `Data` and `Services`.

The `Website` project talks to the `Services` layer. It validates the request being sent, and then, if successful will get the the relevant information from the database inside the `Data` project.

Given this structure, let's have one simple method in each project:

- `Website.GetUsers()` -> calls `Services.GetUsers()`
- `Services.GetUsers()` -> calls `Data.GetUsers()`
- `Data.GetUsers()`

Now we can say that the *upstream caller* for `Data.GetUsers()` is `Services.GetUsers()`. Similarly, the upstream caller for `Services.GetUsers()` is `Website.GetUsers()`.